# aws ec2 nodejs empty body sent through axios post request in react

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, http-headers, postman

I am deploying a MERN app on AWS EC2. Frontend is rendered perfectly on aws. While calling API(axios.post) empty body is received in backend when called through react frontend. But, when called through postman, the body is received correctly.

I am sharing the details of the request body as received on backend(I printed this for debugging purposes):
POSTMAN method:

```
Method: POST
Path:   /api/auth
Body:   { email_id: 'comiiii@gmail.com',
  password: 'comiiii@123',
  user_type: 'type_com' }


Headers:    { host: '64.1.75.248',
  'x-real-ip': '113.103.59.237',
  'x-forwarded-for': '113.103.59.237',
  'x-forwarded-host': 'ec2-64-1-75-248.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com',
  'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
  connection: 'close',
  'content-length': '94',
  'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.26.8',
  accept: '*/*',
  'postman-token': 'a6ef6f75-716b-4843-a773-8b46d1f28427',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br' }
```

REACT FRONTEND:

```
Method: POST
Path:   /api/auth
Body:   {}


Headers:    { host: '64.1.75.248',
  'x-real-ip': '213.235.108.12',
  'x-forwarded-for': '213.235.108.12',
  'x-forwarded-host': 'ec2-64-1-75-248.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com',
  'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
  connection: 'close',
  accept: '*/*',
  'access-control-request-method': 'POST',
  'access-control-request-headers': 'access-control-allow-origin,content-type',
  origin: 'http://ec2-64-1-75-248.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com',
  'user-agent':
   'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  referer: 'http://ec2-64-1-75-248.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' }
```

I saw the difference between the two and realised that the headers which are different are part of forbidden ones. (Refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name)
How to solve this?